# What's a MySQL index table?

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I need to speed up a query. Is an index table what I'm looking for? If so, how do I make one? Do I have to update it each insert?

Here are the table schemas:

```
--table1--   |   --tableA--   |    --table2--
id           |   id           |    id
attrib1      |   t1id         |    attrib1
attrib2      |   t2id         |    attrib2
             |   attrib1      |
```

And the query:

```
SELECT 
  table1.attrib1, 
  table1.attrib2,
  tableA.attrib1 
FROM 
  table1,
  tableA
WHERE 
  table1.id = tableA.t1id
  AND (tableA.t2id = x or ... or tableA.t2id = z)
GROUP BY 
  table1.id
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a composite index on `tableA`:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_tablea_t1id_t2id ON table_A (t1id, t2id)
```

Indexes in `MySQL` are considered a part of a table: they are updated automatically, and used automatically whenever the optimizer decides it's a good move to use them.

`MySQL` does not use the term `index table`.

This term is used by `Oracle` to refer to what other databases call `CLUSTERED INDEX`: a kind of table where the records themselves are arranged according to the value of a column (or a set of columns).

In `MySQL`:

- When you use `MyISAM` storage, an index is created as a separate file that has `.MYI` extension.

  The contents of this file represent a `B-Tree`, each leaf containing the index key and a pointer to the offset in `.MYD` file which contains the data.

  The size of the pointer is determined by the server setting called `myisam_data_pointer_size`, which can vary from `2` to `7` bytes, and defaults to `6` since `MySQL 5.0.6`.

  This allows creating `MyISAM` tables up to `2 ^ (8 * 6) bytes` = `256 TB`
- In `InnoDB`, all tables are inherently ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY`, it does not support heap-organized tables.

  Each index, therefore, in fact is just a plain `InnoDB` table consisting of a single `PRIMARY KEY` of `N+M` records: `N` records being an indexed value, and `M` records being a `PRIMARY KEY` of the main table record which holds the indexed data.